# splitting long regex to pieces PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a very long list of names and I am using preg_replace to match if a name from the list is anywhere in the string. If I test it with few names in the regex it works fine, but having in mind that I have over 5000 names it gives me the error "preg_replace(): Compilation failed: regular expression is too large".

Somehow I cannot figure out how to split the regex into pieces so it becomes smaller (if even possible).

The list with names is created dynamically from a database. **Here is my code.**

```
$query_gdpr_names = "select name FROM gdpr_names";
$result_gdpr_names = mysqli_query($connect, $query_gdpr_names);
    
while ($row_gdpr_names = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_gdpr_names))
{
  $AllNames .= '"/'.$row_gdpr_names['name'].'\b/ui",';
}
$AllNames = rtrim($AllNames, ',');
$AllNames = "[$AllNames]";
$search = preg_replace($AllNames, '****', $search);
```

The created **$AllNames str** looks like this (in the example 3 names only)

```
$AllNames = ["/Lola/ui", "/Monica\b/ui", "/Chris\b/ui"];
```

**And the test string**

```
$search = "I am Lola and my friend name is Chris";
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears that you can't easily handle the replacement from PHP using a single regex alternation, one alternative would be to just iterate each name in the result set one by one and make a replacement:

```
while ($row_gdpr_names = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_gdpr_names)) {
    $name = $row_gdpr_names['name'];
    $regex = "/\b" . $name . "\b/ui";
    $search = preg_replace($regex, '----', $search);
}

$search = preg_replace("/----/", '****', $search);
```

This is not the most efficient pattern for doing this.  Perhaps there is some way you can limit your result set to avoid a too long single alternation.

Comment: How about if you have two matching names in the list. Also, what is the reason for the \b before the name?

Comment: If there are two matching names in the list, then both would be replaced with `****`.  If the same were to occur twice, then both instances would be replaced.

Comment: If I try to echo the $search outside the while it comes empty.

Comment: My guess is that your data has some problem.  What you are seeing might only be possible if every word in the `$search` string matched to some name.  But, even then, there should be some residual whitespace leftover.

Comment: nope, if I print it inside the while, it shows every cycle and it is correct. but printing it outside is just empty

Comment: You need to define `$search` _outside_ of the loop over the result set.  Also, make sure that no other code after the loop might be blanking it out.

Comment: the search is actually defined as a POST value ($search = $json->search;) and I am printing it right after the loop. So, it is super weird. Never seen something like that.

Comment: You're going to need to debug this.  You are in a better position than I to do this.

Comment: sure. I will try to figure out

Comment: @lStoilov Check my updated answer, which hopefully will be working now.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was debugging a lot. Even isolating everything else but this part of code

```
$search = "Lola and Chris";
        $query_gdpr_names = "select * FROM gdpr_names";
            $result_gdpr_names = mysqli_query($connect, $query_gdpr_names);
                    while ($row_gdpr_names = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_gdpr_names)) {
                        $name = $row_gdpr_names['name'];
                        $regex = "/\b" . $name . "\b/ui";
                        $search = preg_replace($regex, '****', $search);
                        
                    }
                echo $search;
```

Still, print inside but not outside the loop.

Comment: I think I know what the problem might be.  `*` is a regex _metacharacter_, so starting with the second iteration of the loop, any `****` from the first replacement would have a special meaning.

Comment: Still the same. it is an absolute mystery.

Comment: And I just find out that it doesn't work only with preg_replace. If I change it with str_replace it will print successfully. The problem is that str_replace will actually replace everywhere where it finds the name, even if it is in the middle of the word.

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually was in the database records. There was a slash in one of the records